# How to make the division of 2 ints produce a float instead of another int?

Tags: java

In another Bruce Eckels exercise in calculating velocity, `v = s / t` where s and t are integers.  How do I make it so the division cranks out a float?

```
class CalcV {
  float v;
  float calcV(int s, int t) {
    v = s / t;
    return v;
  } //end calcV
}

public class PassObject {

  public static void main (String[] args ) {
    int distance;
    distance = 4;

    int t;
    t = 3;

    float outV;

    CalcV v = new CalcV();
    outV = v.calcV(distance, t);

    System.out.println("velocity : " + outV);
  } //end main
}//end class
```

Comment: float v=s/t performs division then transforms result into a float.

float v=(float)s/t casts to float then performs division.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Just cast one of the two operands to a float first.

```
v = (float)s / t;
```

The cast has higher [precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) than the division, so happens before the division.

The other operand will be effectively automatically cast to a float by the compiler because the rules say that if either operand is of floating point type then the operation will be a floating point operation, even if the other operand is integral.  [Java Language Specification, §4.2.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4) and [§15.17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17)

Comment: Grrr, this took me about 30 mins till i found this and figured it out. So simple. :D

Comment: More specifically, this particular rule is mentioned here: [Multiplicative Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third%5Fedition/html/expressions.html#239829), so let it stand here for future reference.

Comment: (For anyone coming across this question later, the given links are broken. The new ones are: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17)

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
v = (float)s / (float)t;
```

Casting the ints to floats will allow floating-point division to take place.

You really only need to cast one, though.

Comment: I don't know, it's like saying that you should use longs instead iof ints.

Answer (score 5):

Cast one of the integers to a float to force the operation to be done with floating point math. Otherwise integer math is always preferred. So:

```
v = (float)s / t;
```

Answer (score 4):

To lessen the impact on code readabilty, I'd suggest:

```
v = 1d* s/t;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the numerator or the denominator to float...

int operations usually return int, so you have to change one of the operanding numbers.

Comment: Usually?  If they return at all, they're going to return int.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast even just one of them, but for consistency you may want to explicitly cast both so something like v = (float)s / (float)t should work.

Answer (score 3):

Cast one of the integers/both of the integer to  float to force the operation to be done with floating point Math. Otherwise integer Math is always preferred.
So:

```
1. v = (float)s / t;
2. v = (float)s / (float)t;
```

Comment: I was lazy to figure out this all by myself, so I searched. I found out that I needed to cast both variables for it to work. So this one worked well

Answer (score 2):

**JLS Standard**

[JLS 7 15.17.2. Division Operator /](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) says:

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have opposite signs.

This is why `1/2` does not give a float.

Converting just either one to float as in `(float)1/2` suffices because [15.17. Multiplicative Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) says:

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands

and [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) says:

> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class CalcV 
{
      float v;
      float calcV(int s, int t)
      {
          float value1=s;
          float value2=t;
          v = value1 / value2;
          return v;
      } //end calcV
}
```