# How can I convert integer into float in Java?

Tags: java, integer, floating-point

I have two integers `x` and `y`. I need to calculate `x/y` and as outcome I would like to get float. For example as an outcome of `3/2` I would like to have 1.5. I thought that easiest (or the only) way to do it is to convert `x` and `y` into float type. Unfortunately, I cannot find an easy way to do it. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: float result = ((float)x) / y?

Comment: check this out: http://xahlee.org/java-a-day/casting.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: dividing 2 ints makes an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/java-dividing-2-ints-makes-an-int)

Comment: I Would suggest you use BigDecimal because floating point (Double, Float) representations and calculations are inexact, leading to erroneous results.

Comment: @VinAy: I would **not** recommend that in this case. `BigDecimal` is not a universally correct replacement for `float`.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah I agree.. but accuracy in Math operations is very important. Better not to write buggy program :)

Comment: @VinAy: It depends entirely what the purpose is. If he is doing finance, you are correct. If he is computing asteroid trajectories, you aren't.

Comment: I usually just multiply by 1.0, is that a bad idea? Like float z = x*1.0/y;

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You just need to **cast** at least one of the operands to a float:

```
float z = (float) x / y;
```

or

```
float z = x / (float) y;
```

or (unnecessary)

```
float z = (float) x / (float) y;
```

Comment: Is this more efficient, than:
 float z = (1.0 * x) / y;
 ? Is float conversion internally more efficient than multiplication? Tnx!

Comment: I don't know, but I think it's irrelevant 99% or more of the time. It's not even remotely going to be a bottleneck. If you're truly that concerned, [benchmark it yourself.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/139010)

Comment: The first and second one will cause errors on certain arm devices, make sure you cast both integers.

Comment: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Comment: @user3002853 read about boxed types vs primitives. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 11):

// The integer I want to convert

```
int myInt = 100;
```

// Casting of integer to float

```
float newFloat = (float) myInt
```

Comment: in Android Studio at least, the compiler will complain about incompatible types trying to do this.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't use float unless you have to. In 99% of cases, double is a better choice.

```
int x = 1111111111;
int y = 10000;
float f = (float) x / y;
double d = (double) x / y;
System.out.println("f= "+f);
System.out.println("d= "+d);
```

prints

```
f= 111111.12
d= 111111.1111
```

Following @Matt's comment.

float has very little precision (6-7 digits) and shows significant rounding error fairly easily. double has another 9 digits of accuracy. The cost of using double instead of float is notional in 99% of cases however the cost of a subtle bug due to rounding error is much higher.  For this reason, many developers recommend not using floating point at all and strongly recommend BigDecimal.

However I find that double can be used in most cases ***provided sensible rounding is used***.

In this case, int x has 32-bit precision whereas float has a 24-bit precision, even dividing by 1 could have a rounding error. double on the other hand has 53-bit of precision which is more than enough to get a reasonably accurate result.

Comment: You should elaborate on _why_ `double` is better than `float`.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to transfer the first value to float, before it gets involved in further computations:

```
float z = x * 1.0 / y;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int x = 3;
    int y = 2;
    Float fX = new Float(x);
    float res = fX.floatValue()/y;
    System.out.println("res = "+res);
}
```

See you !

Comment: Use of a wrapper type (`Float`) is totally unnecessary for this.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Sameer:

```
float l = new Float(x/y)
```

will not work, as it will compute integer division of x and y first, then construct a float from it.

```
float result = (float) x / (float) y;
```

Is semantically the best candidate.

Comment: Your answer should have been a comment. Sameer will receive no notification of your post. Semantically, converting both ints to float before computing the result is needless - therefore it isn't better, than tranforming just one. It gives a wrong impression, and is therefore inferior, imho.