# how to get float value from integer in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert integer into float in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377842/how-can-i-convert-integer-into-float-in-java)

I got the problem with this code.
I have two variable `int i` and `float f`.

`int i = 23;`

float f = i/10;

I suppose the value in `f` variable should be `2.3`

but the real output value in `f` is `2.0`

Why result occurred like this and how can i get the float value `2.3`

Comment: `float f = (float)i/10;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`float f = i/10`

is using integer arithmetic (both numerator and denominator are integers). The result is then promoted to a `float` type.

If you do

```
float f = i/10f
```

then you'll force floating point arithmetic (the denominator is now non-integer). The successive `f` indicates that `10f` is treated as floating point. Specifying `10.0` or `10d` would indicate a double.

Comment: You'll get `double` (and compiler error), not `float`. Should be i/10f

Comment: Whoops. Thx you. Now corrected

Answer (score 5):

The output is 2.0f because both the numerator and denominator are integers hence it is using integer arithmetic.

`i/10` returns `2` which when typecasted to `float`, converted to `2.0f`.

You need to typecast atleast one of the num/denominators to `float` to make FP division

```
int i = 23;

float f = (float)i/10;
```

or

```
float f = i/10f;
```

Possible ways for this.

```
float z = (float) x / y;
```

or

```
float z = x / (float) y;
```

or(not required)

```
float z = (float) x / (float) y;
```

Answer (score 0):

please try 
instead of your
`i/10`   use 
`i/1Of`

Answer (score 0):

You can consider it as a 2 step operation

```
int i = 23;
int tmp = i/10;   
// tmp = 2
float f = (float) tmp;
// f = 2.0f
```

And this is how it looks like in bytecode

```
  L0         //int i = 23;
    BIPUSH 23
    ISTORE 1 // var 1 is 'i'
   L1        // int tmp = i/10;   
    ILOAD 1
    BIPUSH 10
    IDIV     // integer division 
    ISTORE 2 // var 2 - is tmp
   L2        // float f = (float) tmp;
    ILOAD 2
    I2F      // (float) tmp
    FSTORE 3 // var 3 is 'f'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 1;
float f = (float) i;
```