# How to convert an integer value into floating point in java?

Tags: android, integer

I am getting an integer value in my android application.I want to convert it into floating point number which is in this format

> "0.xyF"

.I tried lot of methods.I know its simple but i am confused.Please help.

I am passing a value from one activity to another using putExtra.So in the second activity i have to convert it to float for setting the value as verticalMargin for my dialog window.I used this line for getting the value in second activity.

```
int data = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 7);
```

This is used for setting the vertical margin.

```
wlp.verticalMargin = "the converted floating point number";
```

Comment: what did you try? you want a float or a string representation?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377842/how-can-i-convert-integer-into-float-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Provide sample input/output. [`Float.parseFloat("0." + theInt)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)) *might* do what you expect.. if theInt represents `xy` *and* cannot have leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is the integer value, then try:

```
float f=i;
while(f>=1.0f)
    f/=10.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You question still isn't clear. If you're asking how to convert an integer value that represents a percentage from 0 to 100 into a floating point value, then it would be `fpVal = intVal / 100.0`;

Comment: I got an integer value 48 as result in my first activity which i want to pass to next activity.This value has to be converted into floating point number so that i can use it for setting the vertical margin for my dialog window.Am i clear now ?

Comment: NO, I'm still not sure. I added a separate answer that assumes a completely different meaning to your question. If that still isn't what you're after, perhaps you could provide a couple of before and after values in your question so we can understand your conversion needs.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity store your integer value in string like this

```
String margin = "0."+int_value;
```

then pass this string to second activity.

In the second activity get that string from extra and convert it to float.

```
float float_value = Float.parseFloat(margin);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a simple conversion of an integer into a floating point number with the same exact value (e.g. 7 --> 7.0), then you can just cast it: `fpVal = (float) intVal;`