# Making a integer to a Float

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert an Integer to a Float since I need to use some math and need the decimals offered by floats.

```
public static Float currAccu() {
float accuMiss, accuHit, accuCrit;

accuMiss = Float.parseFloat(publicInt.returnMissCount());
accuHit = Float.parseFloat(publicInt.returnHitCount());
accuCrit = Float.parseFloat(publicInt.returnMissCount());

return 0;
```

The code is incomplete and I'm pretty new at Java. I've used to the Float.parseFloat to convert string to float before. The return will be different, but until I get the conversion working I will continue to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert integer into float in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377842/how-can-i-convert-integer-into-float-in-java)

Comment: Question:  Do you want a `float` or a `Float`?  And is your "integer" in String form or is it an `int`?

Comment: I did actually look at that post, didn't quite understand it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CASTING IS THE SOLUTION**

```
 int b;
 float n = (float) b ;
```

in your case

```
float  accuMiss = (float)(publicInt.returnMissCount());
```