# Java "fractile" method returning wrong output

Tags: java, algorithm

Directions:
Given an `int[] x` and a percentage p (0 - 100), find the smallest valued element `y` of `x` so that at least percentage `p` elements of `x` are less than or equal to `y`.

```
Example 1:
x = {-3, -5, 2, 1}, p = 50 
Method should return -3 
Reason: 50% of the elements in x are less than or equal to -3:  -5 and -3

Example 2:
x = {7, 9, 2, -10, -6}, p = 50 
Method should return 2 
Reason: 60 percent of the elements in x are less than or equal to 2: 2, -10 and -6 
-6 would be wrong because only 40% of the elements are less than or equal
(100% of the elements are less than or equal to 9, but that isn't the smallest value)

Example 3:
x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,7,9,5,43,124,94}, p = 0
Method should return 1
Reason: Only 0% is needed, so in theory any number will do, but 1 is the smallest value
```

---

Here is what I've written for the method so far:

```
public static int fractile(int[] x, int p)
   {
      int smallestInt = x[0];            
      for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         int testNum = x[i];
         int percentage;
         int count = 0;
         for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            if (x[j] <= testNum)
               count++;
         }
         percentage = (count / x.length) * 100;
         if (testNum <= smallestInt && percentage >= p)
            smallestInt = testNum;
      }
      return smallestInt;
   }
```

But my output for my sample numbers comes out wrong:

```
INPUT: 
[6, 5, 4, 8, 3, 2]
40%
Method returns: 6
INPUT: 
[7, 5, 6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9, 10]
20%
Method returns: 7
INPUT: 
[3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2]
60%
Method returns: 3
```

It's almost as if it's grabbing the first index and doesn't look at the numbers behind it but I can't figure out why.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The biggest issue might be your initialization line `int smallestInt = x[0];`. This is simply wrong. Replace it with something like `int smallestInt = Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Robert, do you mean the highest index or highest value?

Comment: Remember, you *must* fix your percentage calculation as described in some of the comments and answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your percentage to double/float and cast one of the variables in divide to double/float as well.

Something like:

```
double percentage=0.0;
...
percentage = ((double)count / x.length) * 100;
```

So the equation returns double/float.

--

> **Numeric Promotion Rules for primitive types**
>
> 1. If two values have different data types, Java will automatically promote one of the values to the larger of the two data types.
> 2. If one of the values is integral and the other is floating-point, Java will automatically promote the integral value to the
>      floating-point value’s data type.
> 3. Smaller data types, namely byte, short, and char, are first promoted to int any time they’re used with a Java binary arithmetic
>      operator, even if neither of the operands is int.
> 4. After all promotion has occurred and the operands have the same data type, the resulting value will have the same data type as its
>      promoted operands.

*by Jeanne Boyarsky & Scott Selikoff - OCA study guide*

Comment: Okay, this worked for my first two outputs. When I got to the 3rd part, it returned "3" when it should have returned "4." This is because 60% of the numbers are NOT less than or equal to 3, only 40% are. {2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7}

Comment: Yep, that is due to the initialization. Fix that too!

Comment: Do you have any recommendations as to how I fix it? The MIN_VALUE idea you suggested didn't work for me. Somebody else suggested sorting the array first-- is this necessary?

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
percentage = (count / x.length) * 100;
```

count and x.length are both integer. Thus, dividing them results in an integer value, not a floating point number. Percentage will probably contain 0 or 100, and not some value in between.

Comment: Would casting to (int) fix this, or would it yield inaccurate results?

Comment: I just tried this and it still returns the same output. I'm not sure that this is the problem.

Comment: It is part of the problem. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377842/how-can-i-convert-integer-into-float-in-java)

Comment: Floris, I figure it may have something to do with initialization, but if I set "smallestInt" to a low value, then testNum will never be smaller. Likewise, I just tried using MAX_VALUE and interestingly enough the output is always returning the highest index now.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is selection algorithm that makes partition of array in given proportion.

Simple and fast one is [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)

And I suspect that there is ready-to-use implementation in Java like C++ `std::nth_element`

Answer (score 1):

For an array which is sorted from lowest to highest you can just multiply the length with the percentage to get the right index of the searched element. For more infos [Quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile)

that will make your code shorter

```
 public static int fractile(int[] x, double p){   
   Arrays.sort(x);       
   int k = (int) Math.ceil(x.length*p)-1;
   return x[k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
public static int fractile( int[] x, int p )
   {
        Arrays.sort(x);
        return x[Math.max((int) Math.ceil(x.length / 100.0 * p) - 1, 0)];
   }
```

This assumes you are allowed to manipulate the array. Sorting an array almost always makes manipulating it easier. This will work unless the array must stay as it is for whatever reason.

This code sorts the array, and since the initial input 'p' tells what percentage you're looking for, it looks at the approximate location in the array and returns the value stored there.

Answer (score 0):

I have another implementation to that problem:

```css
public static void main(String args[]){
  int[] a1 = {-3,-5,2,1};
  int[] a2 = {7,9,2,-10,-6};
  int[] a3 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int[] a4 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,7,9,5,43,124,94};
  int[] a5 = {1};
  int p = 50;
  System.out.println(fractile(a1, p));
 }

 private static int fractile(int[] x, int p) {
  Arrays.sort(x);  
  double value0 = x.length / 100.0 * p;
  double value1 = Math.ceil(value0);
  int value2 = (int)value1; 
  int value3 = value2 - 1;
  int value4 = Math.max(value3, 0);
  return x[value4];
 }
```