# Probability math always output zero?

Tags: java, math, division

so i am creating very simple function to calculate the probability of the repeated words but i found that the probability array are not being initialized ?? the probability always by 0
for example :

```
String original = "abcabd";
String n = "abcd";
int count = 0;
float Probabilty[] = new float[n.length()];

for( int i = 0 ; i < n.length() ; i++){
    for( int j =0 ; j < original.length() ; j++){
        if ( n.charAt(i)== original.charAt(j) ){
            count = count +1;
        }
    }
    Probabilty[i] = count/original.length();
    System.out.println(Probabilty[i]);
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: The array isn't the problem. Use a debugger. Make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the line:

```
Probabilty[i] = count/original.length();
```

Both `count` and `original.length()` are integers, so dividing the two uses integer division. If you convert one to a float or double then you'll get the proper division, like so:

```
Probabilty[i] = ((float)count)/original.length();
```

See [How can I convert integer into float in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377842/how-can-i-convert-integer-into-float-in-java) for a similar question.