# How to divide two large integers in java?

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to divide two large integers,

```
a = 23546654
b = 24979799
```

and to get the result in double.

Comment: You can use double for your a and b variables, that will solve your problems.

Comment: @Marcelo: possible precision loss should be mentioned

Comment: Disagree. Won't work for BigInteger objects, and I think this is what author had in mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: dividing 2 ints makes an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/java-dividing-2-ints-makes-an-int)

Comment: @Mitch I just put a comment up because I wanted to help, but the question doesn't really seem to have enough research.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
double x = ((double) a) / ((double) b)
```

which first converts your ints to doubles and then does the division. If you have `BigInteger`s (which your tag indicates) you may use [`BigInteger.doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#doubleValue%28%29) to extract the double value.

Comment: Actually, double x = a / double(b) would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger class has a `divide` method.

```
BigInteger result = a.divide(b);
```

Comment: Even better would be divideAndRemainder method which will help the OP to get a double/floating point number. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#divideAndRemainder%28java.math.BigInteger%29

Answer (score 1):

This are plain `int` rather than BigInteger.

All you need is

```
double ratio = (double) a / b;
```