# java math result types

Tags: java

I haven't been able to find these rules on a website, (surely because I'm googling the wrong thing) so I'm asking here.

Dividing an int by an int and storing in a double always stores the rounded integer first. The only way I've been able to find to make it work is to cast both values to a double before doing the divide. There's got to be a better way.

Also, where are the rules for the return types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an programming language, there are 2 types of operations:

- Integer Operations
- Floating Point Operations (Float, Double)

If the 2 operands are of Integer type, the Integer operation is executed.
If **ANYONE** of the 2 operands is of Floating Point, the Floating Point Operation is exectued.

**THUS:**

```
Int / Int --------> int
Double / Int -----> Double
Double / Double --> Double
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, no there doesn't have to be a better way.  Dividing an int by an int results in an int.  So, say you divide 5/2 -- since there's no integer between 2 and 3, you get 2. if you want a floating-point result, you need to make one of them a floating type; instead of

```
 int f=5, t=2;
 double result;

 result = f/t;
```

make it

```
 result = f / (double) t ;
```

using a type cast to tell it "I want floating point division dammit!".

Answer (score 1):

You only need to cast one argument to make the result a double

```
int a,b;
double d = (double) a / b;
```

a simpler approach is to use doubles from the start.

```
double a, b;
double d = a / b;
```

`double` can represent every possible `int` value without a rounding error.

Possible duplicate: [How to divide two large integers in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727587/how-to-divide-two-big-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Sure there's a better way.  Just cast one of them to a `double`, the other will be converted automatically.

The type of the expression is determined by the arguments before it is stored, so as other answers state, an `int` divided by an `int` yields an `int`, which will only then be stored as a `double`.  Note that this is not specific to Java, it happens in every language I know of that does integer division.