# Need to return the mean value of an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, average

I am trying to calculate the average of an array list. So far the numbers are added together, however when I try to divide them by the size of the array, it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
public int mean (ArrayList<Integer> number)

{
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (Integer meanInt :number)
    {
        sum+=meanInt;
        counter++;
    }
        return sum / counter;
}
```

Comment: you should return float instead of int

Comment: It's not an array, it's a List

Comment: Could you be more specific about what error you're receiving? I just tried your method, it's working for me.

Comment: "it does not work" how does it *not work*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: dividing 2 ints makes an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/java-dividing-2-ints-makes-an-int)

Answer (score 2):

```
return sum / counter;
```

This can cause an error if `counter` is zero (if `number` is empty). You should take care of that.

Also note that your signature should be `double` and not an `int`. You should explicitly cast one of the sides:

```
return (double)sum / counter;
```

Comment: +1 for noticing the division by zero

Answer (score 1):

In Java8 one would make use of streams and method references like:

```
public float mean (ArrayList<Integer> number) {
    if (number != null && number.size() > 0)
        return (number.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum) / (float)number.size());
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an `int`, which will truncate the value.

You could use a real type such as `float` or `double`, or better:

```
return new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(sum))
    .divide(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(number.size())))
    .doubleValue();
```

**Note**

You don't need a counter for the `ArrayList`'s size, just use the `size()` method as above.

Answer (score 0):

Integer division truncates the fractional part. Instead, return a `float` and cast one of the operands to `float` to ensure correct mathematics:

You can also dispense with `counter`:

```
public float mean (List<Integer> numbers) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer number : numbers) {
        sum += number;
    }
    return (float)sum / numbers.size();
}
```

Note also using more typical variable names.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int number :numbers) sum += number;
    System.out.printf("The sum is: %f\n", (float) sum / numbers.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return double value average can be double also

```
public static double mean(List<Integer> list) {
   if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
    return 0.0;
long sum = 0;
int n = list.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum += list.get(i);
return ((double) sum) / n;
}
```