# LWJGL and Slick - Textures not showing

Tags: opengl, textures, rendering, lwjgl

I've tried to make a simple class for loading spritesheets and drawing 2D textures from it. However, when I try to render one of the sprites, it doesn't do that properly. I either get nothing or just some pink dots (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T8vO.png). Can someone please help me find out what is wrong?

```
public enum Art
{
    GREEN("misc_1", 7, 5, 27, 10),
    BLUE("misc_1", 6, 37, 28, 5),
    MAGENTA("misc_1", 19, 68, 28, 6);

    private String spritesheet;
    private int coordX;
    private int coordY;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    Art(String s, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        this.spritesheet = s;
        this.coordX = x;
        this.coordY = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    public String getSpritesheet()
    {
        return this.spritesheet;
    }

    public void render(int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        if (spritesheets.containsKey(this.getSpritesheet()))
        {
            Texture tex = spritesheets.get(this.getSpritesheet());
            if (glGetInteger(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D) != tex.getTextureID())
            {
                tex.bind();
            }

            float i = coordX / tex.getWidth();
            float j = coordY / tex.getHeight();
            float k = (coordX + width) / tex.getWidth();
            float l = (coordY + height) / tex.getHeight();

            int xx = x + w;
            int yy = y + h;

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(i, j);
                glVertex2i(x, y);
                glTexCoord2f(k, j);
                glVertex2i(xx, y);
                glTexCoord2f(k, l);
                glVertex2i(xx, yy);
                glTexCoord2f(i, l);
                glVertex2i(x, yy);
            glEnd();
        }
    }

    private static boolean isLoaded = false;
    public static HashMap<String, Texture> spritesheets = new HashMap<String, Texture>();

    public static void loadTextures()
    {
        if (!isLoaded)
        {
            try
            {
                Texture misc_1 = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream("res/misc_1.png"));
                spritesheets.put("misc_1", misc_1);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            isLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If it helps, this is what my initGL method looks like:

```
private void initGL()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1280, 720, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

EDIT: I just had to change getWidth() and getHeight() to getImageWidth() and getImageHeight(), that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the definition of your `Texture` class. But I figure that `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return `int` results. If that's the case, you have a problem here:

```
float i = coordX / tex.getWidth();
float j = coordY / tex.getHeight();
```

Both `coordX` and `tex.getWidth()` are values of type `int`, so the division will be carried out as an integer division. Which means for example that if `coordX` is less than `tex.getWidth()`, the result will always be zero.

To get a floating point division, you will need to cast one of the values to a `float`:

```
float i = (float)coordX / tex.getWidth();
float j = (float)coordY / tex.getHeight();
```

See for example this question for more details: [How to make the division of 2 ints produce a float instead of another int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/java-dividing-2-ints-makes-an-int).

Comment: It's actually Slick2D's (slick-util) Texture class, and the returned value is a float. But thanks to you, I just noticed that I have to use getImageHeight() and getImageWidth() instead of getWidth() and getHeight(). That fixed it! Now I just need to figure out how to stop the texture from getting blurred. Thanks again! :D