# Double datatype is not returning decimal values (Java)

Tags: java, double

I was doing a simple GUI program in NetBeans to find area of a circle.
I used double datatype but the answer was not coming properly.
Statement:

```
 double area = (22/7)*r*r; 
 //r is the radius.
```

When I input the value of r as 4, the answer is 48.0.
Why is not coming in proper decimal points ?

Comment: 22 divided by 7 is 3, with a remainder of 1.

Comment: what type is r? integer operations turn out integers as in 22/7

Comment: Because numbers are `int` by default in Java. You should explicitly cast at least one side.

Comment: (And you should use a more accurate approximation of pi.  Use `Math.PI`.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/java-dividing-2-ints-makes-an-int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again

`int` divide by `int` is resulting a `int` value

Then `22/7=3`

So `3*4*4=48`

Change to

```
double area = (22/7.0)*r*r;
System.out.println(area);
```

Out put:

```
50.285714285714285
```

But best way is use `Math.PI` instead of `22/7`

```
double area = Math.PI*4*4;
System.out.println(area);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic operators on native `int` will always return an `int`. Then the result is cast to `double` which is why it comes without the decimal part.

You may fix your code with:

```
double area = (22.0/7.0)*r*r;
```

Comment: Entering (22.0/7)*r*r; also works perfect. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> **Why you are struggling with 22/7? Use Math.PI**

in your case simply use **[MATH.PI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI)** operation as below

```
double area = Math.PI * r * r;
```

**[You can find the all `java.lang.Math` package examples here](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week4/40.html)**

Java 1.6 documentation for **[java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)**

> **The class Math contains methods for performing basic numeric operations such as the elementary exponential, logarithm, square root, and trigonometric functions.**
>
> Unlike some of the numeric methods of class StrictMath, all implementations of the equivalent functions of class Math are not defined to return the bit-for-bit same results. This relaxation permits better-performing implementations where strict reproducibility is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Because the right side is getting evaluated as `int` and then is being converted to `double`.

---

Do it like this

```
double area = (22.0/7.0)*r*r;
```

Comment: Even if I enter double area = (22.0/7)*r*r; The program works just fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you find the answer useful, feel free to accept the answer