# Java giving wrong answer on a calculation

Tags: java, android

i am trying to do some calculations in Java,
but for some reason a simple calculation in 1 or 2 lines of code gives me the wrong answer,
while on the other hand if i do it in 3 steps it works flawlessly.

i know that's it not that bad to do something in a couple more steps,
but why use extra text if it can be shortened??

Could someone give me a pointer if my math is wrong??

this is the 1 line code

```
percent1 = (((totaloutput1Int - Total1Int) / totaloutput1Int) * 100);

also = (((2232 - 1590) / 2232) * 100)
```

and this is the multiple steps code which does work.

```
percent1step1 = (totaloutput1Int - Total1Int);

percent1step2 = ((percent1step1 / totaloutput1Int)* 100);

percent1Tv.setText(String.valueOf(percent1step2));
```

Comment: What (different) results are you getting from the first and second calculations? Also, what types are `percent1` and `percent2`?

Comment: i used all Integers and for percent1step1 and percent1step2 i tried floats, the first calculation is just giving me 2232 and the second one is giving me 28.76344

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `totaloutput1Int` and `Total1Int` from `int` to `double` and everything will work fine.

In the 1st method, int/int leads to rounding off of the value. Which leads to a different result.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked, dammit i was so sure int / int should've worked too xD

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert some of your variables to a double to get an accurate answer. `int` / `int` is going to give you an `int` [Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/java-dividing-2-ints-makes-an-int)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked, dammit i was so sure int / int should've worked too xD

Answer (score 1):

So as this is tagged Android, I'm assuming you are using Android Studio. One of it's great features is in-lining (also available in most modern IDEs).

Take this:

```
float percent1step1 = (totaloutput1Int - Total1Int);

float percent1step2 = ((percent1step1 / totaloutput1Int)* 100);
```

If you rightclick `percent1step1` and select "refactor->inline" android studio will so this:

```
float percent1step2 = ((((float)(totaloutput1Int - Total1Int)) / totaloutput1Int)* 100);
```

So it shows you how to achieve things inline, without multiple lines. In this case the result is convert the `int` from the subtraction in to a `float`.

Comment: hey that's pretty awesome to know :o
this i have to try in the future xD