# LetterCase Count Java

Tags: java, file, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have to read in a file to my project and then read the file line by line to find the percent of upper case and lower case letters. My output should be 4 lines stating the percent of upper and lower for that specific line in the file. This is what I have to far but it doesn't quite work:

```
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int total;
    double percentU = 0.0;
    double percentL = 0.0;




    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        String line = inFile.nextLine();

        for (int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++)
        {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(x)))
            {
                upper++;
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(line.charAt(x)))
            {
                lower++;
            }

        total = upper + lower;
        percentU = upper/total;
        percentL = lower/total;    

        System.out.println("lowercase: " + String.format("%.2f", percentL) + "\t" + "uppercase: " + String.format("%.2f", percentU));
        }



    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: dividing 2 ints makes an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/java-dividing-2-ints-makes-an-int)

Comment: @Caitlin Compagnone try solution below

Answer (score 0):

When you divide an `int` by another `int` the result will be also an `int`. So for example if you divide 30 by 50 the result will be `0` instead of `0.6`.
More information:
[How to make the division of 2 ints produce a float instead of another int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/java-dividing-2-ints-makes-an-int)
[Integer division: How do you produce a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144610/java-integer-division-how-do-you-produce-a-double)
[Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java)

Comment: Of course! Thank you! Unfortunately for some reason the percentages are coming out incorrectly still. The file input is:

Comment: thisTHIS  AAbbCCDDEE  N  UkJ all on separate lines

Comment: Please add a sample input and an expected result to your question

Answer (score 0):

I Just change these lines removed `if (Character.isLowerCase(line.charAt(x)))`:

```
         if (Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(x))) {
                    upper++;
                } 
           if (Character.isLowerCase(line.charAt(x))) {
                    lower++;
                }
```

To:

```
            if (Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(x))) {
                    upper++;
                } else {
                    lower++;
                }
```

And moved these lines out of while loop:

```
 total = upper + lower;
    percentU = (float)upper/total;
    percentL = (float)lower/total;    
    System.out.println("total: " + total);
    System.out.println("lowercase: " + String.format("%.2f", percentL) + "\t" + "uppercase: " + String.format("%.2f", percentU));
```

Try this solution it's ok:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inFile = null;
    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int total = 0;
    double percentU = 0.0;
    double percentL = 0.0;
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp\\file.txt"));

        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            String line = inFile.nextLine();

            for (int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(x))) {
                    upper++;
                } else {
                    lower++;
                }

            }
        }
        total = upper + lower;
        percentU = (float)upper/total;
        percentL = (float)lower/total;    
        System.out.println("total: " + total);
        System.out.println("lowercase: " + String.format("%.2f", percentL) + "\t" + "uppercase: " + String.format("%.2f", percentU));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```