# Using distance formula in Java

Tags: java, formula, distance

I need to use the distance formula to check the distance between my mouse and a moving object. However, my totalDistance continues to return only 1 and I am not sure why.

```
float mouseX = Engine.getMouseX(); //gets X coordinate of the mouse
float mouseY = Engine.getMouseY(); //gets Y coordinate of the mouse

graphic.setDirection(mouseX,mouseY); //object faces mouse
float currentX = graphic.getX();  //gets X coordinate of object
float currentY = graphic.getY();  ////gets Y coordinate of object
double distanceX = (Math.pow((currentX - mouseX), 2)); //calculate (x2-x1)^2
double distanceY= (Math.pow((currentY - mouseY), 2)); //calculate (y2-y1)^2
double totalDistance = (Math.pow((distanceX+distanceY), (1/2))); 
//calculate square root of distance 1 + distance 2
System.out.println("totalDistance = "+totalDistance); //prints distance
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the division of 2 ints produce a float instead of another int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787700/how-to-make-the-division-of-2-ints-produce-a-float-instead-of-another-int)

Answer (score 4):

You should be specifying `double` precision for all your exponent calculations:

```
double distanceX = (Math.pow((currentX - mouseX), 2.0d));
double distanceY= (Math.pow((currentY - mouseY), 2.0d));
double totalDistance = (Math.pow((distanceX+distanceY), 0.5d));
```

Actually, the calculation for total distance was the only place where I saw a big potential problem.  You had this:

```
double totalDistance = (Math.pow((distanceX+distanceY), (1/2)));
```

The problem here is that `(1/2)` will be treated as integer division, and the result will be truncated to 0.

Comment: Or better yet, use [`Math.sqrt(double a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can simply use [`Point2D::distance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance-double-double-double-double-) to calculate the distance between two points.

```
    System.out.println(Point2D.distance(0, 3, 4, 0));
    // prints 5.0
```